# acm.program needs to be included

Tags: java, eclipse

I watched the Stanford online video lecture about java programming by Mehran Sami.

In every program, you need to include the acm.program.

How should I deal with it?

How could I include the acm.program inside the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acm.program sounds like a package, which will contain classes used by the programs created in the lectures.

I assume you downloaded these as a .jar, which you need to add to your eclipse project.
Right click on your project and follow a path, which i think is:

Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add JAR ...

Then select the jar, click ok, and the classes should be available to you.

EDIT:
Once you've done that you can import the classes you need by adding the following line to the top of you java file:

`import acm.program.*;`

or individual classes like:

`import acm.program.DialogProgram;`